# How can i get a list of filename with different patterns using glob npm module

Tags: javascript, node.js, glob

I want to get the list of filename inside multiple directories which contains **file-name** as a string in filename. For example

- file-name.js
- abcd-file-name.js
- file-name-abcd.js
- abcd-file-name-abcd.js

here is what i have done so far

```
var glob = require("glob")

glob(process.cwd() + "/directory/**/*-file-name*.*", {}, function (er, 
 files) {
  console.log(files)
})
```

I am only getting files which contains **abcd-file-name-abcd.js**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should match your required solution

```
var glob = require("glob")
glob(process.cwd() + "/directory/**/?(*|*-)file-name?(-*).*", {}, function (er, 
 files) {
  console.log(files)
})
```

**Resources:**

- [Glob Read Me](https://www.npmjs.com/package/glob)
- [Glob Tutorial](https://dustinpfister.github.io/2017/11/28/nodejs-glob/)